# Delay mouseleave event with AngularUI tooltip

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a tooltip to a button that has a link inside it.  I need to get the tooltip to delay closing right away or allow me to hover over it to click on the link in the tooltip.  I've tried adding a new event using setTriggers, but was unable to get the custom event to trigger.  Look in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2iJ0EIE7wS50BeBVaB4X?p=preview) for an example of how I currently have it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `click` `show` trigger to show the `tooltip`

```
tooltip-trigger="click"
```

Or you can use the `mouseenter` `show` trigger

```
tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"
```

but configure the `show` trigger without the `hide` trigger. So when the mouse cursor moves out, the `tooltip` will not hide.

```
$tooltipProvider.setTriggers({'mouseenter':''})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand that, but I would like it to ultimately fade away after a few seconds so that it doesn't stay on.  Is there a way to get it to fade on mouseleave after a few seconds?